# Dim iPhone screen

Tags: iphone, brightness

I'm working on an application where it may be used in a dark area and the brightness is required to be lowered. I wanted to put this into the application, and thought that I could add a UIView with a black bg color and change the alpha, but this gets in the way of the user interaction.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this without blocking human interaction?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to detect the ambient brightness?

Comment: No, I'm looking to just dim the whole view to alpha of around 0.7f. I've done this by overlaying a UIView and setting the alpha but then you can't control anything underneath it! It because the darkness of where its used, your eyes cant adjust when looking at the screen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the UIView's `userInteractionEnabled` property to NO.

Comment: That's strange. I unticked this in IB and it didn't work. When linking up and calling this, it does! Thanks :)